# Send Extra 1 Custom Email to Admin When New Order is Placed

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, email, custom, sales-order

How to Send an extra **Custom Email** to **Admin** *along with New Order Email is sent* ??

OR Where I can find the **Triggering Method** of *Sending Email of New Order to Administrator* ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default functionality for this.
But to do it, you could implement a small module which hooks on the frontend event `"checkout_onepage_controller_success_action"` which is the success page to which the customer comes after a successful order.

There you can get the last order ID:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
```

and thus load the order and get all the infos you need for your email!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, however if sending a simple copy of the new order email to an admin address will suffice then go to `Admin > System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails > Order > "Send Order Email Copy To"`, enter the email address(es) you want it sent to and select from BCC or Separate email, then hit save.

Comment: I assumed that this is not enough since it was asked for a "Custom Email"?